# Do shastras support the idea of 'good omens' and 'bad omens'?

Tags: scripture, omens

Is it just superstition or mentioned in shastras? Is there any event when omens are considered?

Comment: We have something in either Garuda or Agni Purāṇa I think

Comment: See: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/what-are-some-of-the-good-and-bad-omens

Comment: Also please go through the posts tagged with "omen": https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omens

Comment: @Rickross thanks, will go through it.